# materialize and jquery event onChange

Tags: jquery, onchange, materialize

This night I tried to implement an Ajax call when the user enters a text in the field of a form.

Unfortunately, I use jQuery with the `onChange` event to capture text, but this does not work. It works when I click on text input. It's strange because is so similar to the `onBlur` event.

Any idea?

This is my HTML:

```html
<form class="search" id="search" name="search">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="input-field inline col s4">
     <i class="material-icons prefix">keyboard</i>
     <input id="matrix" name="matrix" type="text" class="validate">
     <label for="matrix">Matrix</label>
   </div>
  </div>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```js
$("#matrix").on('change', function(){ alert('hi') });
```

Comment: I have try the code, it works fine for me. The change event is fired after loseing a focus or validate with `ENTER`. if you want to fired the event on **writing**. Use `.keyup(function(){ alert('hi') })` [JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) , give me a feedback if it works !

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get event on writing,
is like this :

```js
//$("#matrix").on('change', function(){ alert('hi') });

$('form#search input[name=matrix]').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    alert('enter');
    return false;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <form class="search" id="search" name="search">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="input-field inline col s4">
     <i class="material-icons prefix">keyboard</i>
     <input id="matrix" name="matrix" type="text" class="validate">
     <label for="matrix">Matrix</label>
   </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remind you, if you want to get search input value, 
you must add e.key, since $('#matrix').val() would NOT catch the current key you just pressed.

```
$('form#search input[name=matrix]').bind('keypress', function(e) {

                     console.log(e)

                     // must add current key value e.key
                     var _search_for = $('#matrix').val() + e.key;

                    console.log(_search_for);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

bind keypress does not works well, I have a better solution with keyup function.

Please use this instead of keypress. I works for me.

```
    $("#matrix").keyup(function(){


            var _search_for = $('#matrix').val();


 });
```